# Transferring pdf file from an sFtp Server (Complete Ftp) with spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I tryed to execute the example at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/sftp

I tryed to Transfers files from remote to local directory with the example given in the release (sFtpInboundReceiveSample.java)

Therefore, I installed a real sFtp Server (Complete FTP) created an account, generated a private / public key for the user and then tryed to launch tge sample test class.

My goal was to retrieve pdf binary files from the remote sFtp Server and store them in a local directory.

Unfortunately the sample program remain stuck in when trying to receive the first .pdf file.

That is : a temporary test1.pdf.writing file is created but the file is never being completely downloaded.

hence after a while the test end with an error. Can somebody help me determine what to do please ?

below is the configuration I use in my spring .xml file :

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter" auto-startup="false" channel="receiveChannel" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" local-directory="file:local-mumuFolder" remote-directory="mumuFolder" auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="false" filename-regex=".*\.pdf$"> <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1"/> </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

the sample code in java stop here :

public class SftpInboundReceiveSample {

```
@Test
public void runDemo(){
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/integration/SftpInboundReceiveSample-context.xml", this.getClass());
    RemoteFileTemplate<LsEntry> template = null;
    /*String file1 = "a.txt";
    String file2 = "b.txt";
    String file3 = "c.bar";
    new File("local-dir", file1).delete();
    new File("local-dir", file2).delete();*/
    try {
        PollableChannel localFileChannel = context.getBean("receiveChannel", PollableChannel.class);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        SessionFactory<LsEntry> sessionFactory = context.getBean(CachingSessionFactory.class);
        template = new RemoteFileTemplate<LsEntry>(sessionFactory);
        //SftpTestUtils.createTestFiles(template, file1, file2, file3);

        SourcePollingChannelAdapter adapter = context.getBean(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.class);
        adapter.start();

        Message<?> received = localFileChannel.receive();
```

(The localFileChannel.receive() instruction block indefinitively.

Can somebody please help me ?

Thanks and regards

Comment: below is the configuration I use in my spring .xml file :   <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
   auto-startup="false"
   channel="receiveChannel"
   session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
   local-directory="file:local-mumuFolder"
   remote-directory="mumuFolder"
   auto-create-local-directory="true"
   delete-remote-files="false"
   filename-regex=".*\.pdf$">
  <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1"/>
 </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

Comment: Maybe you haven't closed that remote file before dowloading? I mean that the lock on file on the remote server is still obtained.

Comment: Unfortunately the file is correctly closed but I obtain following stack trace :

Comment: @Artem the download work fine for *.txt files or *.xml file on windows but id doesn't work for *.exe files or .pdf

Comment: You really should share the StackTrace for `*.exe` and `*.pdf`

Comment: Dear @Artem I've been executing following test :

Comment: And the behaviour is exactly the seems. Hence I think this issue is related to the library Jsch (at least the version below) can you please confirm :    'code'    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.51</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: Is it really difficult to edit your question and add that code for more readability. Thanks. SI uses the same `jcraft` version

Comment: Sorry Artem I have removed the comment and wil replace them with formatted ones

Comment: @Artem the code can be found here [link]http://kodehelp.com/java-program-for-downloading-file-from-sftp-server/ I only changed the filename, hostanme username and password information

Comment: My problem is that I am still unable to download a pdf file with a size of 2 or more MB. Do you have a idea why please ?